# Single login pulling from multiple tables - SEQUELIZE

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm currently working on a project, which you can find here - https://github.com/thequeueplate/queueplate.

Basically, the problem I have is that I have two different models, and thus two different tables, that deal with Restaurant Owners and Users. We have separate signups, but would (ideally) like to have only a single login that queries both the tables. Is there a way to do that with Sequelize/MySQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way - you'll have to send a separate query to each table / model